# Debian Linux server locked - no clues in the logs?

Tags: debian, server-crashes, proxmox

I had a server lock up this morning.  Here is a screen shot from the console:

[image]

None of the messages from the screen shot mean anything to me.  I have a feeling that the important stuff probably scrolled off the console. I can not find any of the messages from the above screen capture in the syslog, message, dmesg, debug logs or anything logged at all at the time of the crash. Shouldn't this stuff have been logged?

This is a Debian box running Proxmox.  uname output:

2.6.32-4-pve #1 SMP Mon May 9 12:59:57 CEST 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The server has been online for about a year with no other crashes and it booted up again just fine.

I would love to figure out what the issue might have been so that we can prevent it from occurring again in the future.  But, from the evidence I have so far, I don't even know if this was a hardware or software issue.  Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly which Debian kernel release do you run? You can see the full version and revision numbers if you do "dpkg -l | grep linux-image".

It looks like you're hitting a fairly [prevalent bug](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/tip/tip.git;a=commit;h=4cecf6d401a01d054afc1e5f605bcbfe553cb9b9) that I've seen strike numerous times: In kernels before 3.2 mainline, before [2.6.32.50 stable](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/longterm/ChangeLog-2.6.32.50) and before Debian's [2.6.32-45](http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-2.6/linux-2.6_2.6.32-45/changelog#version2.6.32-40) (based on 2.6.32.50 stable), there's a clock overflow that will strike after ~208 days of uptime, which will in turn enable the *potential* of crashing. I don't know exactly what can cause the crash after that time; the patch itself is [pretty vague about it](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/tip/tip.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/include/asm/timer.h;h=431793e5d4846f23bf5947f933fdaf9f5ae1987a;hb=4cecf6d401a01d054afc1e5f605bcbfe553cb9b9#l40) too:

```
Although we may still have enough bits to store the value of ns,
in some cases, we may not have enough bits to store cycles * cyc2ns_scale,
leading to an incorrect result.
```

I've seen upwards of hundred crashes due to this issue, before it was determined what caused it and the patch was deployed.

The bug was [discussed at length](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=132287065112937&w=2) in the lkml at the end of 2011. There could be a possible link to [this divide by zero bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16991), but I haven't found any conclusion.

TL;DR: The likely fix is to upgrade to Debian's linux-image version 2.6.32-**45** or later.

Comment: This server is running Proxmox 1.8 which is based on Debian Lenny 5.0.8... however, I believe the kernel is supplied by OpenVZ: http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Roadmap#Proxmox_VE_1.8

... I will check with the Proxmox guys to see about getting an updated kernel. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention... "dpkg -l | grep linux-image" returned no results (probably because of this being a Proxmox server).

Comment: Since this crash has only happened once, it's hard to say if this is really the cause, but based on the evidence you present here, it seems the most likely cause (need to upgrade the kernel), so I'm marking your answer as being most helpful.  Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a screenshot of a kernel panic.  The traceback is printed inside out, so whatever function finally killed the kernel is off the top of the screen, but starting from the top is a call to `divide_error()` in `hpet_msi_next_event()`  `divide_error()` is defined in the kernel as a trap for [FPE_INTDIV](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L203), so something in `hpet_msi_next_event()` attempted to divide by zero.

Unfortunately, the cause of that could be either hardware, software, or even just a transient bit flip error. (Are you using ECC ram?)

Comment: I'm not sure if this server has ECC or not... I know our server vendor only uses ECC in situations where we request it or the motherboard/cpu combination requires it.  I don't see anything in my notes on this server requesting it, but here is what the invoice says:
ASUS RS100-E6/PI2 1U
Xeon X3430, 2.4G/QC/8M/2.5GTs
16GB RAM -(2x8GB) D3-1333 REx8Q Kingston RAM